# Achartengine library for BarChart in Android

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

I use achartengine library in Project and I want remove bottom title from BarChart, but I don't know, how to remove this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVWxn.png

Comment: Solved. I need add only multiRenderer.setShowLegend(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderer.setShowLegend(false);
```